# GitHub commits were working OK but suddenly: Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

A couple of days ago I was working OK and committing stuff to GitHub without any issues.

Yesterday I started to receive this on "git push":

> Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the
>   list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not
>   read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

1) I have the ssh keys and checked on my GitHub account, the fingerprint matches (ssh-keygen -lf github_rsa.pub).

2) Tried to generate a new key, just in case,it is "github2_rsa", added the public key to GitHub from the web, and changed my ssh config. Changed the IdentityFile to use github2_rsa instead of github_rsa, and added the User=git (a solution recommended to add it)

```
Host github.com
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    User=git
    IdentityFile=~/.ssh/github2_rsa
```

3) Trying to push again, got the same error.

4) ssh -vT git@github.com

```
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/github2_rsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.113' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /.ssh/github2_rsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

My environment is an old virtual machine with WinXP (yes I know, is for a specific env that a project needs), and was using SmartGit to commit, then I tried from the command line when it started to fail, but got the same issue.

Already tried many solutions on StackOverflow and didn't work.

For instance:

Some solutions say "ssh-add xxx" running ssh-add I get:

> Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Others say to use: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" but in windows eval is not recognized as a command.

Comment: Please argument why -1, the question is legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue today on Big Sur where I was suddenly getting `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)` when pushing to GitHub. Reboot didn't help. Ran into this answer which fixed it for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254468/macos-sierra-doesn-t-seem-to-remember-ssh-keys-between-reboots.

In short, the problem was that the ssh agent had lost my ssh keys. Running `ssh-add -A` worked (until next reboot?) but a better solution was to add the following to my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
```

Answer (score -2):

Something similar happened to me yesterday and no matter what I was doing with SSH, it simply wouldn't let me push.

The solution in my case was more than stupid. I just had to restart iterm (iterm2). I have no idea have you tried that, but hopefully it will work if you just restart the whole process.

Comment: Thanks but "My environment is an old virtual machine with WinXP" not MacOS

Comment: I have read and understood that. That’s why I wrote to “restart the process”, hoping that whichever technology you use maybe just maybe something as silly as restarting it might save you. :) Anyway, good luck and hopefully someone will have a proper solution soon. Best, N.

Comment: restarting the terminal (console) process in windows is just closing and opening a new console, did that like 20 times while testing solutions, nothing worked.